# Date validation to specific year for list Column in view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, column, column-validation, formula

I've got a date column in a view and I'm using a validation formula:

```
=IF(TEXT([Data documento],"yyyy")="2018",TRUE,FALSE)
```

So that users can only insert date within the year 2018.

- I always get an error when saving the formula, how come?
- One more question, not quite related, should we mainly do validation through Powerapps forms? Is this the best practice that MS is suggesting for sharepoint?

I'm using sharepoint 365

[image]
[image]

I've also tried inserting the formula as Michael Han_MSFT suggested:

```
=TEXT([Data documento],"yyyy")="2018"
```

But unfortunately I still get an error message as shown below
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need change the validation formula to this:

```
=TEXT([Data documento],"yyyy")="2018"
```

Try to use this in list validation. Go to list settings-> validation settings:

[image]

Comment: still getting an error message: "Sorry, something went wrong
The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported". Is there some kind of debugger we could use? The only way I can sudo replicate the formula is in Excel.

Comment: Per my test, it works and I didn't get any errors. Make sure you enter the formula correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I still get an error message. For what It's worth I've updated the question with the image of the error. I have a love/hate feeling towards sharepoint.

Comment: It's strange. Besides, you could try to use list validation instead of column validation and see if it work. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below formula:

```
=TEXT([columnname],"yyyy")="2018"
```

I tried using `TEXT(created,"yyyy")="2018"`

Please do it on list validation. by going through `List Setting-->Validation Setting`.